# GWT: How do I properly set height of a StackLayoutPanel?

Tags: gwt, height, panel

I'm using GWT 2.4.  I want to construct content sections using the StackLayoutPanel widget.  Howevr, I'm having trouble sizing the widget vertically to take up as much space as possible.  I'm discovering

```
    p.setHeight("100%");
```

doesn't actually do anything.  Does anyone have any advice for calculating the proper height for the StackLayoutPanel so that it takes up as much space as possible but not more?  Here's the code I'm using ...

```
    final StackLayoutPanel p = new StackLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    p.setHeight("100%");
    int i=0;
    for (final Node node : nodes) { 
        if (node != null) { 
            final Widget childWidget = getWidget(node.getChildren());
            if (childWidget != null) { 
                final String sectionTitle = node.getAttributes().get(NAME_ATTR) != null ? node.getAttributes().get(NAME_ATTR).getValue() : "Section " + (i+1);
                p.add(childWidget, sectionTitle, 2);
            }   // if
        }   // if
        i++;
    }   // for
    return p;
```

Here is the code that ultimately calls the StackLayoutPanel.  Notice that the parent widget, "ScrollPanel", sets height="100%", but that has no effect on causing the StacklayoutPanel to fill out all of its space.

```
            final ScrollPanel childpanel = new ScrollPanel();
            childpanel.setHeight("100%");
            // Below, a StackLayoutPanel is returned as the child widget
            final Widget childWidget = xmlToHtmlService.getWidget(tabNode.getChildren());
            childpanel.add(childWidget);
```

Thanks, -

Answer (score 0):

The best way to size a `LayoutPanel` of any type is to `add` it to another `LayoutPanel` and set its size from the parent panel.  Setting the size directly never works like I want it to.

This a pretty different setup from the other GWT widgets, which just want to be added and sized.  You can read about it at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels .

There's a lot to learn about `LayoutPanel`s.  Once you've got them set up properly, though, they're very natural to use, and you can do a lot of precision layout with them.

Comment: Hi, I'm already doing that -- I included code above.  I set the parent ScrollPanel's height to be 100% but still StackLayoutPanel doesn't adjust to fit the height of the parent.  Is StackLayoutPanel unique in this respect?